# Writing into a txt file from XmlNodeList in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Is it possible to write every element from an XmlNodeList into a .txt file and how would it be done. No parsing is necessary, I just want to write it into a txt file.  I'm trying to accomplish it with StramWriter but so far no luck. For now, I do this by creating a string that holds the node (it's inner XML + opening and closing tag) but since I have a large number of nodes to go trough, this is very slow.

Comment: wat u r looking to write in to text file?

Comment: The basic idea is this - I have a big XML file (around 52000 entries) that I need to decompose into 3 smaller files. I loaded that file into a XmlDocument, and then by using xpath filtered it and populated the XmlNodeList. Now I just want to write everything from thet XmlNodeList (every letter of every element) into a new file.

Comment: Ah ... whatever u do take a warning XmlDocument is memory hungry and creates huge file (although there are tricks). Using .Net 4? If so consider the XDocument classes.

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5. The size of the file is not that important (I doubt that it will exceed few hundred MB-s, and that is acceptable).

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText("myFile.txt"))
{
  foreach (node in nodeList)
  {
      writer.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);   // InnerXml to get only the content
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using XmlDocument. It has a couple of save methods.

However XmlDocument is very memory hungry so if your list is long it may not be the best option. Also it uses space indenting (by default) so the file may be large.

But all is easy if your list is small.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not, and that is why I'm having this problem in the first place. Can you please look at my answer to Rajeshes comment in the question, it will give you more informations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, this could help you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

did you mean :

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = ...;
String txt = "";
foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in nodeList)
{
    txt += xmlNode.OuterXml;
}
File.WriteAllText("xmlFile.txt",txt);
```

for more performance over large data use `StreamWriter`

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("Path"))
{
    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in nodeList)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(xmlNode.OuterXml);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way I'm doing it now, but since I have 30000 entries per condition, it takes too long to execute, so I'm trying to find a faster way